# Angular-cli + ngx-bootstrap : acive multiple modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a for loop and in this loop I have multiple element who need a modal in it.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let nut of allnutrients; let i=index">
      <span class='info-link'><span (click)="staticModal.show()"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></span>

       <div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             ....
       </div>
 </ng-container>
```

but obviously this code don't work because the #staticModal is defined multiple times.

How can I programmatically create modals basing the name on *{{ nut.name | lowercase }}* or the index *i* ?